# Is it possible to call a stored procedure within an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-insert

In a nutshell, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertingStuff
    @value1
AS
    INSERT INTO [my_table] (column1, column2)
    VALUES (@value1, execute sp_anotherSP)
GO
```

What I need to know is: is it possible to execute a stored procedure from within an `INSERT` statement like that? If there's a better way to do this I'm open to the advice. The reason I need to do something like this is because I need to run some IF statements to get the value for that second column.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need a stored procedure to do the job you want. We cannot help you on this, unless you give us some details on what your actual problem really is.

Comment: Is it possible that these "IF statements" could instead be replaced by `CASE` *expressions*, and so make the logic *declarative* rather then *procedural*?

Comment: Never name a stored proc sp_ that is the prefix the system uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

execute the second one just above the insert statement inside the first sp
like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertingStuff
    @value1
AS
    declare @value2 int
    exec @value2 = sp_anotherSP

    INSERT [my_table] (
        column1, 
        column2
    )

    VALUES (
        @value1, 
        @value2
    )
GO
```

Comment: I'll look into some of the other answers supplied but this one achieved the required result, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute a sp in the `VALUES` part.  You have to execute and get the return/out value before insert, like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertingStuff
    @value1
AS

    DECLARE @anotherValue INT 
    execute @anotherValue = sp_anotherSP

    INSERT [my_table] (
        column1, 
        column2
    )

    VALUES (
        @value1, 
        @anotherValue
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add OUTPUT parameter in you sp_anotherSP
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx
and

```
DECLARE @Val <type>
EXEC sp_anotherSP @Val OUTPUT
... insert using @val
```

Answer (score 0):

One mentioned solution is to add an OUTPUT parameter. Another is to rewrite your stored procedure as a function, as long as your stored procedure doesn't already UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE any data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done by making the temp table in the insert sp.
then call the sp that you want to call and store the value in the temp table and then you can use that temp table values in your sp and at last drop that temp table